# Change base classes of an object to the same value

Tags: python

I have an object `a`

Will `a` be the same if I do this?

`a.__class__ = type(a.__class__.__name__, a.__class__.__bases__, {})`

Comment: No, for starters you pass an empty dict to the new type so any methods and class attributes will be gone. `a` will also no longer be an instance of the original class so `isinstance` checks will fail along with lots of other unexpected behaviour

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "same". Clearly, it's `__class__` attribute will have changed. While it's true that changing that attribute doesn't change any *other* instance attribute, there's no guarantee that `a` will have been *initialized* correctly for an instance of the new type.